# PROBLEMA LOGIN LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, login

tengo un problema con el login de laravel, el que se crea automáticamente con el comando:

> php artisan make:auth

Realice el comando para iniciar el login enseguida, y al probarlo me aparece tal error:

> auth.failed

Cabe destacar no hice ninguna modificación en el código, y ese es el unico error que aparece el cual no me dice nada, alguien sabe que es?, espero su ayuda le adjunto una foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te salta como `auth.failed` por que no tienes los archivos lang, vasicamente el error dice: `Estas credenciales no coinciden con nuestros registros.`

Comment: sabes como solucionar este tema?

Comment: si tienes seteado `'locale' => 'es',` en config/app.php, puedes crear un archivo como [este](https://github.com/Laraveles/spanish/blob/master/resources/lang/es/auth.php) en `/resources/lang/es/auth.php` o instalar un paquete que lo haga por tí, por ej https://github.com/Laraveles/spanish

Comment: instale el paquete pero no me lo soluciono :c

Comment: ya entendi mi problema, es que en password de mi bd no lo estaba pasando encriptado entonces, no me los leia

Comment: Son dos problemas distintos, uno es lo que causa el error, y otro el mensaje que te muestra debajo del input

Comment: @MatiasMuñoz Por curiosidad que versioln de laravel estas usando? ya que en la 6 me suena de haber leido que auth ahora es un paquete independiente, por este motivo es posible que no tengas los archivos de i18n de auth. El codigo funciona, lo que te esta diciendo es que el usuario y contraseña no coinciden con los de la base de datos.

Comment: si, ya entendí mi problema, el error estaba en mi tabla users que cree yo, ademas las contraseñas que tenia en mi BD no estaban encriptadas, eso hacia que no coincidan las credenciales, gracias por la preocupación (Laravel 5.8)